# How to insert menu within several fragments?

Tags: android, layout, menu

I have a layout like this:

[image]

There are 4 fragments- but I want that I can slide the Fragment 1 and (List)Fragment 3 (together) like a menue to the left and right (see arrow in picture) depending on the orientation of phone ( landscape show everything, if not show fragment2 + fragment 4 - and fragment 1 and 3 as menu to slide in)

When I click o an element on Listfragment3 it shall open the new content in fragment 4.

What would be the best way to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `DrawerLayout` or `SlidingPaneLayout`.

Comment: yes it worked but I have still a problem:

i want the left menu only overlaps when device is vertical.

if it is horizontal it shall show the menue every time...hmm

Comment: I don't know which solution have you chosen, but if you're using `DrawerLayout` in horizontal orientation use `DrawerLayout#openDrawer` to show menu and `DrawerLayout#setDrawerLockMode` to disable interaction with the menu.

Comment: i've tried to solve it :

 if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
           /**
           * Landscape mode of the device
           */
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }else{
           /**
           * Portrait mode of the device
           */
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }


I have two different main layouts,.. one with drawer and the second one without - so it works, but I would wish to work only with one main layout

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you really want. Well, to have overlapping menu in vertical orientation and two 'panes' next to each other in horizontal orientation you unfortunately have to deal with two separate layouts. Consider leaving requirement for overlapping menu and basing your solution on `SlidingPaneLayout`.